# setTimeout variable value is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am implementing a functionality where user will get a popup if the user session is about to expire prior one minute. In the popup there are two buttons "OK" and "Cancel". If the user clicks on "OK" button an AJAX POST call is made to server. 
Below is the Code I have written -

```
        var sessionTimeoutWarning = parseInt(@Session.Timeout - 1);
        var sessionTimeout = @Session.Timeout;
        var sessionWarningTimer = null;
        var sessionExpireTimer = null;

        //For Session Expire Warning Popup
        var sessionWarningTimer = setTimeout('startTimer()', parseInt(sessionTimeoutWarning) * 60 * 1000);

        //For Session Expired Popup
        var sessionExpireTimer = setTimeout('showLogoutModal()', parseInt(@Session.Timeout) * 60 * 1000);

        function showLogoutModal() {
            $("#session-expired-modal").modal('show');
        }

        function startTimer() {
            $("#session-expire-warning-modal").modal('show');

            var count = 60;
            var timer = setInterval(function () {
                $("#seconds-timer").html(count--);
                if (count == -1) {
                    clearInterval(timer);
                    $(".modal-body").html("Your session is expired.");
                }
            }, 1000);
        }

        function executeAjaxCall() {

            $.ajax({
                url: '/Home/SessionTimeout',
                dataType: "json",
                async: false,
                type: "POST"                
            });
        }

        $("#btnOk").click(function () {

            executeAjaxCall();                       

            $("#session-expire-warning-modal").modal('hide');

            alert(sessionWarningTimer);
            alert(sessionExpireTimer);

            if(sessionExpireTimer != null)
            {
                alert("here");
                clearTimeout(sessionExpireTimer);
            }

            //For Session Expire Warning Popup
            var sessionWarningTimer = setTimeout('startTimer()', parseInt(sessionTimeoutWarning) * 60 * 1000);

            //For Session Expired Popup
            var sessionExpireTimer = setTimeout('showLogoutModal()', parseInt(@Session.Timeout) * 60 * 1000);

        });

        $("#btnExpiredOk").click(function () {

            $("#session-expire-warning-modal").modal('hide');
            $("#session-expired-modal").modal('hide');

            window.location = "/Home/Index";
        });

        $("#session-expire-warning-modal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function () {
            $("#session-expire-warning-modal").modal('hide');
        });

        $("#session-expired-modal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function () {
            $("#session-expire-warning-modal").modal('hide');
            $("#session-expired-modal").modal('hide');

            window.location = "/Home/Index";
        });
```

Now, the problem is that after the AJAX is made the value of `sessionWarningTimer` and `sessionExpireTimer` are `undefined`.

Comment: Please check @Session.Timeout getting value?

Comment: Where you are writing this code? in JS file or cshtml (razor)?

Comment: How can this code be written in JS file? ofcourse this is in the partial view (cshtml) in the shared layout view

Comment: yes that's y i cheked.

Answer (score 0):

You are re-declaring `sessionExpireTimer` and `sessionWarningTimer` a lot of times. Seems to me like a scope problem.

I would recommend that you start your js with `"use strict"` to prevent these kind of problems.

In short, try removing the `var` keyword on the button click callback:

```
//For Session Expire Warning Popup
sessionWarningTimer = setTimeout('startTimer()', parseInt(sessionTimeoutWarning) * 60 * 1000);
//For Session Expired Popup
sessionExpireTimer = setTimeout('showLogoutModal()', parseInt(@Session.Timeout) * 60 * 1000);
```

So you will be assingning values to the previously declared vars and not re-declaring them into this function scope

Comment: Do you mean scope? Or is scoop some new cool programming-lingo i have not heard of? :)

Comment: Sorry @adam-azad I have to rollback because of some changes I made were lost

Comment: @Edorka I have tried using "use strict" but I didn't get any errors for any variable. So this is not an issue which scope related.

Comment: Yes, indeed strict mode doesn't prevent redeclaring variables. Only thing left is removing those var on the button callback as suggested later.

Comment: We are going to need a jsfiddle or similar, but I would only put sessionWarningTimer and sessionExpireTimer declarations and the beginning and removing any other.